# Trying to save picture to a particular Pictures folder that has not been created

Tags: android, camera, save, directory, image

I managed to get `photo1.jpg` to save to the `Pictures/mockFolder` I created on the SD card, here's the code for future reference.

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{

    final int PICTURE_ACTIVITY = 1; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/mockFolder/"; 
        File newdir = new File(dir); 
        newdir.mkdirs();
        String file = dir + "photo1.jpg";
        File newfile = new File(file);
        try {
            newfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {}       

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PICTURE_ACTIVITY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        AlertDialog msgDialog;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            msgDialog = createAlertDialog("Alert", "Picture was not saved. Please try again.", "OK");

        } else {

            msgDialog = createAlertDialog("Alert", "Picture was saved successfully.", "OK");
        }       
        msgDialog.show();
    }

    private AlertDialog createAlertDialog(String title, String msg, String buttonText){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog msgDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        msgDialog.setTitle(title);
        msgDialog.setMessage(msg);
        msgDialog.setButton(buttonText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int idx){
                finish();
            }
        });

        return msgDialog;
    }

    public void finish()
    {
        super.finish();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to create your new File too.
After you have done `File file = new File(path);`, call `createNewFile()`;
Or rather:

```
String dir = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "mockFolder/"; 
String name = "photo1.jpg"; 
File file = new File(dir, name); 
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: You don't find the folder in the Gallery immediately after you create it. The Gallery needs to re-scan the SD card to detect new folders/files created since it last checked.

Comment: @kaciula So how do I find out if it's been created?

Comment: You can activate usb sharing on your phone and look in the folders manually.

Answer (score 4):

You could improve your code by calling `newFolder.mkdirs()` instead of `newFolder.mkdir()`. `mkdirs()` creates all the folders needed in the path specified.

Also, you forgot to add a slash after `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` when you set the path variable.

Also, make sure your app has permission to write to the sd card.

Add this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

`Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` only contains the folder name for the pictures. You need to provide a full path to the location.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: Good point, although I've been editing my code since I posted the question and found that quite a while ago. Thanks though!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Do you have permission set in your app to write to the sd card? This would explain why the activity hangs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and get back to you. I didn't know what I was doing was writing to the SD card. I was hoping to write to internal memory, is that possible?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference. I've checked the SD card as well and nothing has been created on it.

Comment: Updated the answer again. You need to specify the full path to the picture in order for the camera app to know where to save the pic.